# How do I use jq to flatten a complex json structure?

Tags: json, jq, flatten, recursive-datastructures

I have the following simplified json structure: Notice an array of values, which have children, whose children could have children.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "12",
      "text": "Beverages",
      "state": "closed",
      "attributes": null,
      "iconCls": null
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "text": "Foods",
      "state": "closed",
      "attributes": null,
      "iconCls": null,
      "children": [
        {
          "id": "33",
          "text": "Mexican",
          "state": "closed",
          "attributes": null,
          "iconCls": null,
          "children": [
            {
              "id": "6100",
              "text": "Taco",
              "count": "3",
              "attributes": null,
              "iconCls": ""
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I flatten a json structure using jq? I would like to print each element just once, but in a flat structure. An example output:

```
{
  "id": "12",
  "category": "Beverages"
},
{
  "id": "10",
  "category": "Foods"
},
{
  "id": "33",
  "category": "Mexican"
},
{
  "id": "6100",
  "category": "Tacos"
}
```

My attempt doesn't seem to work at all:

```
cat simple.json - | jq '.value[] | {id: .id, category: .text} + {id: .children[]?.id, category: .children[]?.text}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`..` is your friend:

```
.. | objects | select( .id and .text) | {id, category: .text}
```

Comment: Ah - I see from the [docs](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#recursive-descent) that `..` is the same as the `recurse` function and that the no-args `recurse` is equivalent to `recurse(.[]?)`

Answer (score 2):

If your actual input is that simple, recursively extracting *id* and *text* from each object under *value* should work.

```
[ .value | recurse | objects | {id, category: .text} ]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/x1_oyREeQW)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> I was totally going in the wrong direction

Not really.  Going in that direction, you would have something like:

```
.value[] 
| recurse(.children[]?) 
| {id, category: .text}
```